# Permutation of cartesian product

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

> $$
> \DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn} |X|=m,\, |Y|=n,\, \sigma \in S_X, \, \tau \in S_Y. 
> \\\xi \in S_{X \times Y},\, \xi(x, \ y) = (\sigma(x),\, \tau(y)),\, x \in X,\, y \in Y
> $$

1. I need to find $\sgn \xi$, if $\sgn \sigma$ and $\sgn \tau$ are specified.
2. I need to find lengths of independent cycles in $\xi$ expansion, if lengths $k_1,\dots,k_s$ and $l_1,\dots,l_t$ of independent cycles in $\sigma$ and $\tau$ expansions are specified.

I solved first point of the task in the following way: let $r$ be number of transpositions in $\sigma$ and $q$ number of transpositions in $\tau$, $r_i$ and $q_j$ are specific transpositions in $\sigma$ and $\tau$ respectively.
$$
\xi = \bigl((x),r_1\bigr), \dots, \bigl((x),r_n\bigr) \bigl((q_1),(y)\bigr), \dots, \bigl((q_m),(y)\bigr); 
\quad x = 1,\dots,m;\; y = 1,\dots,n. 
$$

So, total number of transpositions is $m \cdot r + n \cdot q$. It means that $\sgn \xi = (\sgn \sigma)^m \cdot (\sgn \tau)^n$.

Second point of the task seems unclear to me. I don't understand how independent cycles in $\xi$ expansion look like.

I tried to use the second point of task for finding another solution for the first one: $\sgn \xi = (-1)^{mn - \sum_{i=1}^s \sum_{j=1}^t gcd(k_i,l_j)}$

But the answer is $\sgn \xi = (\sgn \sigma)^n \cdot (\sgn \tau)^m$.
It means that $\sgn \xi = (-1)^{2mn - sn - tm}$
.So, I need to prove that $mn - \sum_{i=1}^s \sum_{j=1}^t gcd(k_i,l_j)  \equiv - sn - tm(mod \ 2)$. I don't really know how to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For determining the sign, you have a small mistake. Each transposition $(i\;j)$ in $\sigma$ corresponds to $n$ transpositions in $\xi$, switching $(i,y)$ with $(j,y)$ for each $y\in Y$. Similarly, each transposition in $\tau$ gives $m$ transpositions in $\xi$. Therefore, $\text{sign}(\xi)=\text{sign}(\sigma)^n\,\text{sign}(\tau)^m$. You had the $m$ and $n$ backwards.

---

For the cycle structure, let us consider a simple case. Say that $X=\{0,1,\dots,m-1\}$ and $Y=\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$, while $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are the permutations defined by
$$
\sigma(x)=x+1\pmod m,\qquad x\in X\\
\tau(y)=y+1\pmod n,\qquad\; y\in Y
$$
Let us find the cycle structure of $\xi$ in this case.

**Claim:** The number of cycles of $\xi$ is $\gcd(m,n)$, and each cycle has length $\text{lcm}(m,n)$.

*Proof:* The permutation $\xi$ is defined by
$$
\xi(x,y)=(x+1\pmod m, \;\;y+1\pmod n)
$$
Let $d=\gcd(m,n)$. The following $d$ pairs are all in different cycles:
$$
(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),\dots,(0,d-1)
$$
Indeed, you can check that $\xi$ preserves the value of $y-x\pmod d$ as it acts on ordered pairs $(x,y)$. Since all of the above have different values of $y-x\pmod d$, they must be in different cycles.

All that remains to show is that those $d$ pairs, when $\xi$ is repeatedly applied to them, generate all of the pairs $(x,y)\in X\times Y$. First, note that for any integer $k$, that
$$
\xi^{km}(x,y)=(x,y+km\pmod n)
$$
In particular, since there exists an integer $k$ for which $km\equiv d\pmod n$ (you can prove this using Bézout's lemma), this means there exists $k$ such that
$$
\xi^{km}(x,y)=(x,y+d\pmod n)
$$
Now, starting from the set of tuples $\{(0,i)\mid 0\le i\le d-1\}$, and repeatedly applying $\xi^{km}$, you get all tuples of the form $(0,y)$ for $y\in Y$. Then, by repeatedly applying $\xi$ to $\{(0,y)\mid y\in Y\}$, you can get all of $X\times Y$.
$\tag*{$\square$}$

Using the **claim**, you can prove the following. If $\sigma$ has $s$ cycles with lengths $k_1,\dots,k_s$, and $\tau$ has $t$ cycles with lengths $l_1,\dots,l_t$, then for each $i\in \{1,\dots,s\}$, $j\in \{1,\dots,t\}$,
$$
\text{$\xi$ has $\gcd(k_i,l_j)$ cycles of length $\text{lcm}(k_i,l_j)$.}
$$
This follows by breaking up $X$ and $Y$ into the cycles of $\sigma$ and $\tau$, and considering for each cycle $C_X$ in $X$ and $C_Y$ in $Y$, how $\xi$ acts on $C_X\times C_Y$. Up to permutation, every cycle of length $r$ is of the form $z\mapsto (z+1)\pmod r$, which is why the claim applies.

Comment: An alternative to showing that every $(x,y)$ is reached is showing that each of the disjoint cycles has length $\text{lcm}(m,n)$. With that, the fact that $mn = \gcd(m,n)\text{lcm}(m,n)$ means that all elements of $X \times Y$ have been accounted for.

Comment: I don't understand why $\xi$ preserves the value of $y - x (mod \ d)$. Is it some kind of fact from number theory?

Comment: @Arthur_Kitsuragi As long as neither $x$ nor $y$ "wrap around" when changing from $(x,y)$ to $(x+1,y+1)$, it should be clear that the difference $y-x$ is unchanged. When there is a wrap-around, say that we go from $(m-1,y)$ to $(0,y+1)$, the difference changes from $y-(m-1)$ to $y+1-0$, so the difference changes by $m$. However, since $m\equiv 0\pmod d$, as $m$ is a multiple of $d$, the difference changes by $0$ modulo $d$. The same is true when we wrap around in the $y$ coordinate. Does this make sense?

Comment: @MikeEarnest yep, now this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I will use the notation $\sigma \times \tau$ to denote the permutation $\xi$ has you have defined it, so that
$$
(\sigma \times \tau)(x,y)= (\sigma(x),\tau(y)).
$$
I will use id to denote the identity permutation.

Your process for the first part is close but not quite correct. Your decomposition can be written as follows: if $\sigma = \sigma_1 \circ \cdots \circ \sigma_r$ is a decomposition of $\sigma$ into transpositions and $\tau = \tau_1 \circ \cdots \circ \tau_q$ a similar decomposition for $\tau$, then
$$
\sigma \times \tau = (\sigma_1 \times \text{id}_{Y})\circ \cdots \circ (\sigma_r \times \text{id}_{Y}) \circ (\text{id}_X \times \tau_1)\circ \cdots
\circ (\text{id}_X \times \tau_q).
$$
Given a transposition $\sigma_i$ that swaps elements $a$ and $b$ in $X$, the map $\sigma_i \times \text{id}_Y$ is a composition of $n$ disjoint transpositions: for each of the $n$ elements $y_1,\dots,y_n$ of $Y$, we have
$$
(\sigma_i \times \text{id}_Y)(a,y_j) = (b,y_j), \quad j = 1,\dots,n
$$
and $\sigma_i \times \text{id}_Y$ leaves all other elements of $X \times Y$ unchanged. Thus, if $\sigma_i^j$ denotes the transposition over $X \times Y$ swapping the elements $(a,y_j)$ and $(b,y_j)$ (and leaving other elements unchanged), then
$$
\sigma_i \times \text{id}_Y = \sigma_i^1 \circ \cdots \circ \sigma_i^n.
$$
Analogously, we can decompose
$$
\text{id}_X \times \tau_i = \tau_i^1 \circ \cdots \circ \tau_i^m.
$$
Thus, we conclude that $\sigma \times \tau$ is a composition of $nr + mq$ transpositions, leading to the result
$$
\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma \times \tau) = (\operatorname{sgn}\sigma)^n \cdot (\operatorname{sgn}\tau)^m.
$$

---

For the second task, we are now given cyclic decompositions for $\sigma$ and $\tau$. Redefining previous notation, we'll take $\sigma = \sigma_1 \circ \cdots \circ \sigma_s$ to be a decomposition of $\sigma$ into disjoint cycles such that $\sigma_i$ is a cycle of length $k_i$. Similarly, let $\tau = \tau_1 \circ \cdots \circ \tau_t$ be a cyclic decomposition of $\tau$. We can write
$$
\sigma \times \tau = (\sigma_1 \times \text{id}_{Y})\circ \cdots \circ (\sigma_s \times \text{id}_{Y}) \circ (\text{id}_X \times \tau_1)\circ \cdots
\circ (\text{id}_X \times \tau_t).
$$
Consider a fixed $1 \leq i \leq s$ and $1 \leq j \leq t$. Suppose that the cycles $\sigma_i,\tau_j$ are given by
$$
\sigma_i = (x_1\ \ \cdots \ \ x_{k_i}), \quad \tau_j = (y_1 \ \ \cdots \ \ y_{l_j}).
$$
Consider the set $\{x_1,\dots,x_{k_i}\} \times \{y_1,\dots,y_{l_i}\} \subset X \times Y$. Note that of the terms in the above decomposition of $\sigma \times \tau$, the only terms that act upon these elements are $\sigma_i \times \text{id}_Y$ and $\text{id}_X \times\tau_j$. We conclude that this is an invariant subset of the permutation and that, over this set, the behavior of $\sigma \times \tau$ is the same as the behavior of $\sigma_i \times \tau_j$.

> **Claim:** Given cyclic permutations $\alpha,\beta$ with lengths $k,\ell$ respectively, the permutation $\alpha \times \beta$ can be decomposed into $\gcd(k,\ell)$ disjoint cycles of length $\text{lcm}(k,\ell)$.

Mike has an excellent proof of this in his answer, I see no need to reproduce it.

With this claim, we can conclude that for each $1 \leq i \leq s$ and $1 \leq j \leq t$, the cyclic decomposition of $\sigma \times \tau$ contains $\gcd(k_i,l_j)$ cycles of length $\text{lcm}(k_i, l_j)$.

---

Incidentally, all of this connects to the properties of the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product): if $S$ is the permutation matrix associated with $\sigma$ and $T$ the permutation matrix associated with $\tau$, then $S \otimes T$ is the permutation matrix associated with $\sigma \otimes \tau$.

The formula for the sign of $\sigma \times \tau$ is confirmed by the formula for the determinant of $S \otimes T$,
$$
\det(S \otimes T) = \det(S)^n \det(T)^m,
$$
together with the fact that the determinant of a permutation matrix is the sign of its associated permutation.

The cyclic properties are a bit more difficult to confirm, but can ultimately be deduced as a consequence of how the eigenvalues of permutation matrices connect to cycle lengths.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I had just noticed the error, thanks.